# How can I access devices on a second router on the network?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

- **Router1**: I have an ISP provided modem/router.
- **Router2**: I have another router (which I cannot install DD-WRT on).

Router2's WAN port is connected to a LAN port on Router1 and I use Router2 to connect to a VPN using a PPTP setup. All devices connected to Router2's WiFi will get internet access through the VPN. All devices connected to Router1 will get normal internet access.

The problem is that I cannot access SAMBA shares of devices on Router2 from devices on Router1.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Very old question, but the solution in 2024 might be to purchase a cheap Ethernet switch to replace the 2nd router. Much simpler to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of connecting the WAN port on router 2 to the LAN port on router one, connect router via the LAN port as well and that should resolve the issue. Also, make sure only one router is acting as DHCP server, if both are, they will be on different subnets.

Comment: I cannot use Router2 as an access point because then I cannot connect to the VPN.

Comment: Then why don't you use Router 1 as an access point?

Comment: That doesn't solve the OPs problem. Which is different internet access for different subnets.

Comment: Router1 doesn't work as an access point.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration explained is not clear enough but I will try to help you. There are several ways to solve your problem.

The easiest one is to connect both routers with an ethernet cable and assign a different IP for each one in the same subnet, for instance 192.168.1.1 for Router1 and 192.168.1.2 for Router2 with mask 255.255.255.0.

For the devices that you want internet through the VPN you must configure manually the gateway 192.168.1.2 and for the normal users you can keep the automatic configuration.

Comment: How do I "configure manually the gateway 192.168.1.2"?

Comment: This link may help you http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/

Comment: @AngelSanchis Sorry to say, the link is dead in 2024.